# Check the presence of word suggestions/ dictionary in iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uikeyboardtype

How can I check if my keyboard in iOS displays the dictionary or word suggestion (I don't know the right term).

[image]

I've search through the net but I didn't found an answer. 
Behind those word suggestion/ dictionary is my input field, but when the word suggestion/ dictionary is presence it is been hidden behind it. I want my input to put it dynamically on the top of the word suggestion/ dictionary whenever they are present. To do it I just need a notification whenever word suggestion/ dictionary is present. Is anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

I also do not know what the suggestion bar term ...

But you can use NSNotificationCenter to observe the keyboard resize notifications

Try it.

Maybe help~

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    //add UIKeyboardWillShowNotification to NSNotificationCenter
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification{

    //Should Log when keyboard show or resize         
    NSLog(@"keyboard notification");

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    //Get the keyboard
    NSValue *keyBoardValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    //Get the keyboard Rect
    CGRect keyboardRect = [keyBoardValue CGRectValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGRect:keyboardRect]);
}
```

Then when you operate the keyboard

you should look something like...

```
keyboard notification
NSRect: {{0, 228}, {320, 252}}
keyboard notification
NSRect: {{0, 264}, {320, 216}}
keyboard notification
NSRect: {{0, 228}, {320, 252}}
keyboard notification
NSRect: {{0, 264}, {320, 216}}
keyboard notification
NSRect: {{0, 228}, {320, 252}}
```